# Изменить имя сайта на локальном компьютере

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени, помогите советом. Нужно изменить имя сайта с `www.op.ru` на `www.Up.ru`.
Папку `C:\WebServers\home\Up` переименовал. В файле WP-config '`DB_NAME`', и '`DB_USER`' изменил на `Up`. А еще в самих настройках Wordpress изменил в верхних двух строчках старый адрес на новый.
Теперь не могу попасть никуда! Или советом или ссылочкой помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может, в hosts-e еще изменить надо в `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

В базе данных в 1 или 2 записях таблицы настроек хранится доменное имя сайта.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант первый:** заходим через phpmyadmin в базу данных и меняем в таблице wp_options у строк 2 и 38 адрес домена на ваш.

**Вариант второй:** в файл **config.php**
добавьте строки:

```
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.Up.ru'</a>);<br>
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.Up.ru'</a>);
```

вот и все.

Comment: Предметно, спасибо. Исправил через phpmyadmin файл siteurl, помогло.