# Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, faq

При переносе WordPress сайта с локального компьютера на сервер (или наоборот) сайт перестает работать. Аналогичная проблема возникает и при смене домена, по которому сайт доступен.

Признаки неработоспособности бывают самые разные - не отображаются некоторые страницы, не отображаются картинки в библиотеке медиафайлов, не грузятся стили, не работают слайдеры, и т.д., и т.п.

В чем причина такого поведения и как правильно перенести WordPress сайт или сменить его домен?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Как правильно переносить сайт? (TL;DR)**

Надо использовать программные средства, специально предназначенные для этого. Упомянутые ниже программы корректно работают с сериализованными данными, пересчитывая длину строк.

Самым простым и автоматизированным решением лично мне представляется плагин [Duplicator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/), который снимает копию локального сайта, предоставляет для скачивания 2 файла: .zip и installer.php, которые надо перенести на новый сервер и там запустить installer.php. Все остальное плагин проделает автоматически. В большинстве случаев имеет смысл переносить только базу с помощью этого плагина, а файлы копировать по FTP.

Скрипт [Database Search and Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) поможет корректно внести изменения в базу. Для этого пользователь должен, правда, понимать, что он делает, знать, например, какие пути на старом сайте и какие - на новом.

Плагин [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) позволяет корректно подготовить базу для миграции. Для завершения процесса пользователь должен использовать phpMyAdmin для импорта базы на новом сервере.

[Интерфейс командной строки для WordPress (WP-CLI)](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/cli) позволяет конвертировать базу одной командой. Например, для конвертации `http://site.ru` в `https://site.org`:

```
wp search-replace --url=http://site.ru http://site.ru https://site.org --recurse-objects --report-changed-only --precise --skip-columns=guid --skip-tables=wp_users --skip-plugins --skip-themes
```

С мультисайтом ситуация несколько сложнее. Плагины Duplicator и [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) переносят их только в платной версии.

Мне неизвестны бесплатные плагины для переноса мультисайтов. Если хочется сделать перенос мультисайта бесплатно, то можно скопировать базу, а потом воспользоваться Database Search and Replace.

**Причины проблем при переносе**

В **первую очередь** проблемы возникают потому, что **все ссылки в базе WordPress хранятся как абсолютные**. Например, ссылка на иконку сайта выглядит примерно так:

```
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-test-favicon.png
```

Для правильной работы сайта на новом домене (например, `https://newsite.org`) ссылка в базе должна измениться на

```
https://newsite.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-test-favicon.png
```

Обратите внимание на то, что даже при простом переводе сайта с `http` на `https`, все ссылки внутри базы надо менять!

За использованием абсолютных ссылок в WordPress лежат серьезные доводы. Почитайте [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516783/6817117) на английском StackOverflow, в котором даны объяснения. В том числе, приведено мнение одного из ведущих разработчиков WordPress. Единственная проблема, которая возникает при использовании абсолютных ссылок - перенос сайтов. Однако перенос сайта с относительными ссылками в общем случае ещё более проблематичен. В упомянутом ответе это тоже обсуждается.

**Вторая причина** проблем при переносе - **сериализованные данные** в базе. Все современные плагины (включая WooCommerce, слайдеры, различные визуальные редакторы типа Visual Composer), темы - хранят данные в базе в сериализованном виде. Это упакованные в строки массивы и объекты. Несколько примеров:

Информация о последнем отредактированном файле из темы twentyseventeen:

```
(39, 'recently_edited', 'a:3:{i:0;s:46:\"/var/www/test/wp-content/themes/test/style.css\";i:2;s:50:\"/var/www/test/wp-content/themes/test/functions.php\";i:3;s:0:\"\";}', 'no'),
```

Данные Jetpack

```
(5104, 'jpsq_sync-1494597052.351881-573008-5', 'a:6:{i:0;s:21:\"jetpack_sync_constant\";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:7:\"ABSPATH\";i:1;s:14:\"/var/www/test/\";}i:2;i:1;i:3;d:1494597052.351856;i:4;b:0;i:5;a:9:{s:12:\"display_name\";s:4:\"kagg\";s:10:\"user_email\";s:12:\"info@kagg.eu\";s:2:\"ip\";s:14:\"87.110.237.209\";s:7:\"is_cron\";b:0;s:11:\"is_wp_admin\";b:1;s:7:\"is_rest\";b:0;s:9:\"is_xmlrpc\";b:0;s:10:\"is_wp_rest\";b:0;s:7:\"is_ajax\";b:0;}}', 'no'),
```

Данные популярного плагина бэкапа сайтов BackWPUp

```
(5884, 'backwpup_jobs', 'a:1:{i:1;a:32:{s:5:\"jobid\";i:1;s:10:\"backuptype\";s:7:\"archive\";s:4:\"type\";a:3:{i:0;s:6:\"DBDUMP\";i:1;s:4:\"FILE\";i:2;s:8:\"WPPLUGIN\";}s:12:\"destinations\";a:1:{i:0;s:6:\"FOLDER\";}s:4:\"name\";s:15:\"Database backup\";s:14:\"mailaddresslog\";s:12:\"info@kagg.eu\";s:20:\"mailaddresssenderlog\";s:28:\"BackWPup test <info@kagg.eu>\";s:13:\"mailerroronly\";b:1;s:13:\"archiveformat\";s:4:\".zip\";s:11:\"archivename\";s:24:\"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%i-%s_%hash%\";s:11:\"fileexclude\";s:51:\".DS_Store,.git,.svn,.tmp,/node_modules/,desktop.ini\";s:10:\"dirinclude\";s:0:\"\";s:19:\"backupexcludethumbs\";b:0;s:18:\"backupspecialfiles\";b:1;s:10:\"backuproot\";b:0;s:17:\"backupabsfolderup\";b:0;s:13:\"backupcontent\";b:0;s:13:\"backupplugins\";b:0;s:12:\"backupthemes\";b:0;s:13:\"backupuploads\";b:0;s:21:\"backuprootexcludedirs\";a:0:{}s:24:\"backupcontentexcludedirs\";a:1:{i:0;s:7:\"upgrade\";}s:24:\"backuppluginsexcludedirs\";a:1:{i:0;s:8:\"backwpup\";}s:23:\"backupthemesexcludedirs\";a:0:{}s:24:\"backupuploadsexcludedirs\";a:0:{}s:9:\"backupdir\";s:32:\"uploads/backwpup-a34fdc-backups/\";s:10:\"maxbackups\";i:7;s:18:\"backupsyncnodelete\";b:0;s:7:\"lastrun\";d:1510222228;s:7:\"logfile\";s:98:\"/var/www/test/wp-content/uploads/backwpup-a34fdc-logs/backwpup_log_a34fdc_2017-11-09_10-10-28.html\";s:21:\"lastbackupdownloadurl\";s:129:\"http://test.kagg.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=backwpupbackups&action=downloadfolder&file=2017-11-09_10-10-28_SKRU7XDQ01.zip&jobid=1\";s:11:\"lastruntime\";d:1;}}', 'no'),
```

во всех примерах можно найти путь к папке сайта на сервере: `/var/www/test/`.

Вот пример сохраненных настроек из очень популярного SEO-плагина Yoast

```
(291, 2, 'wp_yoast_notifications', 'a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:\"message\";s:309:\"The configuration wizard helps you to easily configure your site to have the optimal SEO settings.<br/>We have detected that you have not finished this wizard yet, so we recommend you to <a href=\"http://test.kagg.eu/wp-admin/?page=wpseo_configurator\">start the configuration wizard to configure Yoast SEO</a>.\";s:7:\"options\";a:8:{s:4:\"type\";s:7:\"warning\";s:2:\"id\";s:31:\"wpseo-dismiss-onboarding-notice\";s:5:\"nonce\";N;s:8:\"priority\";d:0.80000000000000004;s:9:\"data_json\";a:0:{}s:13:\"dismissal_key\";N;s:12:\"capabilities\";s:14:\"manage_options\";s:16:\"capability_check\";s:3:\"all\";}}i:1;a:2:{s:7:\"message\";s:768:\"We\'ve noticed you\'ve been using Yoast SEO for some time now; we hope you love it! We\'d be thrilled if you could <a href=\"https://yoa.st/rate-yoast-seo?utm_content=4.8\">give us a 5 stars rating on WordPress.org</a>!\n\nIf you are experiencing issues, <a href=\"https://yoa.st/bugreport?utm_content=4.8\">please file a bug report</a> and we\'ll do our best to help you out.\n\nBy the way, did you know we also have a <a href=\'https://yoa.st/premium-notification?utm_content=4.8\'>Premium plugin</a>? It offers advanced features, like a redirect manager and support for multiple keywords. It also comes with 24/7 personal support.\n\n<a class=\"button\" href=\"http://test.kagg.eu/wp-admin/?page=wpseo_dashboard&yoast_dismiss=upsell\">Please don\'t show me this notification anymore</a>\";s:7:\"options\";a:8:{s:4:\"type\";s:7:\"warning\";s:2:\"id\";s:19:\"wpseo-upsell-notice\";s:5:\"nonce\";N;s:8:\"priority\";d:0.80000000000000004;s:9:\"data_json\";a:0:{}s:13:\"dismissal_key\";N;s:12:\"capabilities\";s:14:\"manage_options\";s:16:\"capability_check\";s:3:\"all\";}}i:2;a:2:{s:7:\"message\";s:162:\"Don\'t miss your crawl errors: <a href=\"http://test.kagg.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_search_console&tab=settings\">connect with Google Search Console here</a>.\";s:7:\"options\";a:8:{s:4:\"type\";s:7:\"warning\";s:2:\"id\";s:17:\"wpseo-dismiss-gsc\";s:5:\"nonce\";N;s:8:\"priority\";d:0.5;s:9:\"data_json\";a:0:{}s:13:\"dismissal_key\";N;s:12:\"capabilities\";s:14:\"manage_options\";s:16:\"capability_check\";s:3:\"all\";}}}'),
```

Здесь мы видим в сериализованных данных строку с упоминанием домена: `href=\"http://test.kagg.eu/wp-admin/?page=wpseo_configurator\"`. Она мало того, что сериализована, да ещё и экранирована (`\"`).

**Третья причина** - наличие в базе **путей к файлам**. Они могут быть не только от корня WordPress, но и от домашнего каталога пользователя хостинг-аккаунта или даже от корня веб-сервера (некоторые плагины так делают). Пути могут быть представлены как обычными строками, так и сериализованными данными (первый пример выше). При переносе на другой хостинг их тоже надо менять.

Что произойдет, если просто перекинуть базу как есть на новый сервер? Очевидно, перестанут работать вещи, связанные с путями к файлам и ссылками, содержащими предыдущий домен.

**Что надо делать?** Очевидно, менять пути к файлам на новые и имя домена в базе. Вопрос, как. Совершенно непригодны **три плохих совета**, которые часто можно встретить:

1. Заменить в базе в таблице `wp_options` записи c `option_name` = `siteurl` и `home` на новое имя домена. Работает только на самых примитивных сайтах.
2. Сделать дамп базы в файл .sql, и провести текстовые замены путей и домена, затем залить базу на новый сервер. Это прямой путь к разрушению базы. Сериализованные данные при этом будут безнадежно испорчены.
3. Послать несколько SQL-запросов, которые произведут замену домена. То же самое, что и выше - это прямой путь к разрушению базы. Сериализованные данные будут безнадежно испорчены.

Рассмотрим первый пример выше с сериализованными данными. После текстовой замены `/var/www/test/` на, скажем, `/home/i/account-name/site-name.org/public_html` (как на одном популярном хостинге), из строки

```
s:46:\"/var/www/test/wp-content/themes/test/style.css\"
```

получится строка

```
s:46:\"/home/i/account-name/site-name.org/public_html/wp-content/themes/test/style.css\"
```

Только ее длина уже ни разу не 46 символов, и WordPress не сможет прочитать эти сериализованные данные из базы.

Таким образом, **все три "популярных" совета надо признать вредными**.

Comment: Стоит поправить - не "все ссылки", а "все внутренние ссылки". И ты хотя и сказал про пути, но как-то между прочим. Стоит акцентироваться на этом  Это как раз самое важное. Зачастую важнее урла. И что ещё - некоторые плагины хранят пути, заэкранировав слеши. (некстген и ревослайдер напр). Это нужно учитывать. А еще некоторые юзеры то с www, то без оного внутри используют - такая каша получается :)

Comment: А, ида. "перенести".. "перенести на др хостинг"  и "перенести на др домен" и  несколько разные вещи. А второе может быть как со сменой физ. расположения так и без оного.

Comment: @SeVlad да все ссылки хранятся как абсолютные, так что текст правильный. А исправлять надо внутренние, согласен. но вроде это и так понятно.

Comment: @SeVlad я дал как раз примеры, связанные с путями (перенос на другой хостинг) и со сменой домена. Это два варианта, которые могут сойтись в одном перемещении сайта.

Comment: >но вроде это и так понятно Может быть понятно не всем :) Прецеденты были :) А текст-то правильный, конечно. Но я к тому, что стоит акцентировать про пути - именно из-за их смены основной масса сериалов валится.

Comment: @SeVlad добавил про пути, как третью причину проблем.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71302/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-sevlad).

Comment: @SeVlad написал на Мете вопрос-ответ, прими участие, а? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress/6689#6689

Answer (score 3):

Используйте плагин WP All-in-one Migration и Вы не будете сталкиваться с такими проблемами!

Answer (score 0):

1.Имя домена локального сервера должно быть идентичным имени домена реального, вплоть до протоколов HTTP и HTTPS с WWW и без WWW. Если это не так, сделайте его идентичным.

2.Исправьте пути в если они не совпадают.

3.Вы переносите сайт на другой тип сервера к примеру у вас Apache (на локальном), а на реальном сервере установлен nginx php-fpm - многие плагины могут не работать, по причине безопасности кода php, либо плохой конфигурации сервера, к примеру, код может не выполнятся если он обрамлен в

```
<? /*code here*/ ?>
```

вместо

```
<?php /*code here*/ ?>
```

4. Таже после переноса, перед тем как зайти на сайт, очистите кэш браузера и отключите локальный сервер.

Comment: >Имя домена локального сервера должно быть идентичным имени домена реального, вплоть до протоколов HTTP и HTTPS с WWW и без WWW  А если мне надо перенести на другой домен? Вот что тогда? А  как исправлять пути - конкретно? К этому ответу вопросов больше, чем в нем написано.

Comment: > многие плагины могут не работать, по причине безопасности кода php, либо плохой конфигурации сервера  

Это не плохая конфигурация сервера, и не безопасность кода, а сокращенные теги php. Параметр задается в файле php.ini.

Сокращенные теги крайне не рекомендуются стандартами кодирования WordPress: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/

Если у вас такой код с `<?` вместо `<?php`, то его надо править, безотносительно сервера, а от использования плагинов с таким кодом следует отказаться.

Comment: Чтобы не было проблемы ее не нужно создавать. Если на другой домен, смотря как автор его переносит. Тут нужно писать целый FAQ по тому как правильно работать с путями, и как правильно переносить домен, учитывая и не учитывая возможные ошибки. Для детального ответа нужно знать как именно автор переносит домен, на какой тип сервера, какие конкретные ошибки выводятся.

Comment: Что значит, не надо создавать? Мне регулярно приходится туда-сюда таскать сайты с боевого хостинга и домена типа site.ru на мой сервер с доменом типа site.kagg.eu. А весь FAQ по переносу я написал в моем ответе. В конце - конкретные рекомендации. Работают при любых раскладах.

Comment: Если вы работает только с одной платформой wp - это не выход. Будет время я напишу универсальное решение этой проблемы. Чтобы не носились туда сюда, но это будет касаться только одной платформы wordpress.

Comment: Что значит - с одной платформой? У вопроса метка wordpress, если вы не заметили. И почему не выход? Куда не выход?

Comment: Я так понял Вы вопрос задали и сами ответили ? На счет выхода, не знаю как работает дубликатор, но можно придумать универсальное решение данных 3 глобальных вами описанных проблем включая пути в плагина и шаблонах.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71304/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-webstackoverload).